# Data saved using a trigger (AFTER INSERT) in PostgreSQL is deleted when I use Django to save it

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, pgadmin

I'm working on a project using Django REST framework and PostgreSQL.

3 tables are involved, location, crime and location_crimes. The user can create a location using a postcode and the system find all the crimes that are inside that location (using an stored procedure) and saves them into the location_crimes table.

I tested the trigger and the procedure directly in the DB and they work as expected.

The problem is when I call one endpoint to create a new location. After the insert, I use a Django signal to print the data inserted using a raw query, just for testing.

I discovered that the trigger works because I managed to return the data from that table with the expected result (with the inserted data returned from both tables). But when I check the database the information is not there, and the Dashboard from pgAdmin shows a DELETE is occurring right after the insert;
[(DB chart)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgHh4.png)

I suspect there is a rollback or a commit not occurring but the pgAdmin dashboard doesn't show any problem.

Thank you for your help.

**VIEW**

```
class LocationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   """Manage locations in the DB"""
   authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
   permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

   queryset = Location.objects.all()
   serializer_class = serializers.LocationSerializer

   def get_queryset(self):
       """Return Locations for the current auth user only"""
       crimes = self.request.query_params.get('crimes')
       queryset = self.queryset

       return queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)

   def perform_create(self, serializer):
       """Create new location"""
       serializer.save(user=self.request.user)


def find_crimes_from_location(sender, **kwargs):
   # this print the expected result
   res = sender.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM core_location L LEFT JOIN core_location_crimes C ON C.location_id = L.id WHERE L.id = '+ str(kwargs['instance'].id))
   for row in res:
       kwargs['instance'].crimes.add(row.crime_id)
       print(row)


post_save.connect(find_crimes_from_location, sender=Location)
```

**MODEL**

```
class Location(models.Model):
"""Location object created by user"""
user = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
postcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
coords = ArrayField(models.DecimalField(
    max_digits=10, decimal_places=8), size=2)
crimes = models.ManyToManyField('Crime')
region = models.ForeignKey('Region', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```